# Import Specific Files from Folder into Access Table

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

**Background:**

I receive a daily sales files that I would like to import into access automatically. They are currently saved to a specific folder with a consistent naming convention. I don't review these files everyday and would like to make the import process a push button procedure. There are other files in the folder that I don't need, so I can't just import the entire file.

**File Naming Convention:** DAILY.SALES.20160611

(the 20160611 is the Year - 2016, Month - June, and Day 11th)

**Help needed:**

I can import all the files, but I can't figure out how to specify only those files that begin with "Daily.Sales". Below is the code I have that can import everything without specifying. My assumption is that it has something to do with the path or strFile, but none of the variations that I've tried has worked.

It would be nice if the code could actually check if the file has already been uploaded before uploading it, however, if I have to delete the table after each use and re-upload everything that is still easier.

```
Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
path = "C:\Desktop\Test\"

   Dim objXL As Object
   Dim wb As Object

   Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

   strFile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
   While strFile <> ""

       Set wb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path & strFile)

       If wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") <> "No Data" And wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") <> "" Then
           'add files to the list
           intFile = intFile + 1
           ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
           strFileList(intFile) = strFile
       End If
       strFile = Dir()
Debug.Print strFileList(intFile)
       wb.Close False
       Set wb = Nothing
   Wend

'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

'cycle through the list of files
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
filename = path & strFileList(intFile)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Stage", filename, False

Call Format_Staging_Table
Call Copy_from_Stage_to_Master
Call Clear_Staging_Table

Next intFile
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

You can ignore the Call pieces, they are to format the data once I get it in...

Thanks for any help or advice that anyone might be able to provide!

Comment: Do you want this? `strFile = Dir(path & "Daily.Sales*.xls")`

Comment: "none of the variations that I've tried has worked" - hard to understand what you've tried - Just about any DOS file seacrh spec will work - @HansUp suggestion is simple enough and works - as does `"Daily.Sales.*.xls"` and `"Daily.Sales.????????.xls"` - and then you say "t would be nice if the code could actually check if the file has already been uploaded before uploading" - You're using MS-Access - that's a database I assume you're using to do more than transfer spreadhseets? It will easily handle that with simple log file table and update recordset and a query to check if it's in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just answered a question like this 1 minute ago.  I think you should take a look at this link.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWktsSepTbl

Just modify that to suit your needs...  Basically...change the path and folder to match your file name...