# How to upload all files in a folder into MS ACCESS (SQL Query)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question about SQL query in MS ACCESS.

I have 5 EXCEL file in `C:\Users\Usuari\Desktop\DATA`

[image]

If I want to upload Excel file, every time I upload Excel file one by one (`External Data-> New Data Source-> From_File-> Excel`). If there are only 5 files, it would be okay, but if there are 100 files, it would not be possible to upload one by one.

Could you tell me how to upload multiple files or all files in a folder?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you had done a search on SO, you could have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839227/import-specific-files-from-folder-into-access-table .   Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, in the link where you presented, the code is VBA, not SQL query, isn't it? I want to know SQL query.

Comment: AFAIK, Access query object cannot connect to Excel file and VBA is needed to automate import. Review http://accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

Comment: Thanks June7. This information is so useful!! Thanks!!